# Handling multiple users and cases in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, watir, gherkin

I am writing a Rails testing suite using Cucumber.

I currently have a scenario which is very much like this.

```
Scenario Outline:
  Given I am logged in as "<user>"
  When I create a <fruit>
  Then I should see the <fruit> info
  When I click the <fruit> delete button
  Then I should see the confirmation "Fruit deleted"

  Examples:
    | user   | fruit  |
    | super  | apple  |
    | super  | banana |
    | ninja  | apple  |
    | ninja  | banana |
    | juicer | apple  |
    | juicer | orange |
    | cake   | apple  |
    | cake   | banana |
    | cake   | orange |
```

This works fine, but it doesn't seem very DRY. I would prefer something like this.

```
Scenario Outline:
  Given I am logged in as "<user>"
  When I create a <fruit>
  Then I should see the <fruit> info
  When I click the <fruit> delete button
  Then I should see the confirmation "Fruit deleted"

  Examples:
    | user   | fruits                |
    | super  | apple, banana         |
    | ninja  | apple, banana         |
    | juicer | apple, orange         |
    | cake   | apple, banana, orange |
```

Is this sort of thing possible? Am I even headed in the right direction with my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible to change your examples to group the fruits in a single scenario. Each of the steps would have to:

1. Take the string of fruits
2. Split them on the comma (assuming no fruits have a comma in them)
3. Perform the action for each fruit

For example, your "Then I should see  info" would look like:

```
Then /I should see the (.*) info/ do |fruit_array|
    fruits = fruit_array.split(',').map(&:strip)

    fruits_on_page = ['apple', 'banana', 'grape']

    fruits.all? do |fruit|
        fruits_on_page.should include fruit
    end
end
```

In terms of whether it is a good idea or not, I believe the recommendation would be to use your first approach with each individual fruit being an example. The reason being that having just one assertion per test (scenario) is easier to understand and debug. However, there could be reasons to combine the tests. For example, if each example takes an hour to run, perhaps you would save time by combining them. If there is an interaction with fruits, then it might make sense to combine them to test that interaction. Another reason for not changing it, is that while your scenarios might look dryer, you step definitions are now more complicated. As well, making multiple assertions in a step can be bad since only the first failed assertion is reported (though there are hacks to address this).

Comment: +1 for explanation. I agree with this, very close to my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Two annotations:

- If you just need to test if one (or two) user(s) can do CRUD actions on your app, perhaps you just split the use cases:

  - CREATE

    - userA can create a fruit named "banana"
    - userB can create a fruit named "banana"
  - DELETE

    - userA can delete a fruit named "banana"
    - userB can delete a fruit named "banana"
  - $ANOTHER ACTION

    - ...
- There's a syntax error in your second feature: in the Examples section, the second column is "fruit", not "fruits"

Of course, you can use Cucumber's scenario outlines in a different DRYer way :-)

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines

Comment: This is less dry than before. And I put `fruits` because I was giving an example of running the same user for multiple fruits.

Comment: This *might* my DRYer than yours, it depends by other details. I've just shown a different and more coherent way to write Gherkins, IMHO.

The fact that you used "fruits" sounds as a syntax error, considering that you are using the same steps.

I've also linked a wiki page that shows some approaches.

Comment: How would you handle it in the above case when not all users can create a banana?

Comment: I would create a Scenario Outline, with two kind of users (one with permissions, and one without), then I check that each of them can/can't create bananas.
the Examples would contain User data (eg: name, perms) and a fruit type. So I can check *who can do what*.

Comment: Btw, it all depends from *what* are you trying to test in your feature. Is it about permissions? about CRUD with fruits? I usually don't mix things. In case, I prefer to share common Steps.

Comment: Well it would be testing whether each user could create/delete the specified fruit type.

Comment: This was a terrible edit review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3001829 Please don't review any more edits if you're going to let these things slip through.

Comment: @meagar first of all, this isn't the right place to put a comment about reviewing another post. However, the only reason I approved those edits was because that post was unreadable. the edits did not affect or change the content of the question.

Comment: @AndreaPavoni That edit **fundamentally** altered the code in the question,  rendering the question invalid. It should never have been approved. Do **not** approve question edits which change the code.